# In calculus, absolute convergence implies convergence. Why is the proof so weirdly complicated?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, absolute-convergence

Here is the standard proof I got from Paul's math notes

> First notice that $\left| {{a_n}} \right|$ is either ${a_n}$ or it is
> $- {a_n}$ depending on its sign. This means that we can then say,
>
> $$0 \le {a_n} + \left| {{a_n}} \right| \le 2\left| {{a_n}} \right|$$
> Now, since we are assuming that $\sum {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}$ is
> convergent then $\sum {2\left| {{a_n}} \right|}$ is also convergent
> since we can just factor the 2 out of the series and 2 times a finite
> value will still be finite. This however allows us to use the
> Comparison Test to say that $\sum \left({{a_n} + \left| {{a_n}}\right|}\right)$ is also a convergent series.
>
> Finally, we can write,
>
> $$\sum {{a_n}} = \sum \left({{a_n} + \left| {{a_n}} \right|}\right) -\sum {\left| {{a_n}} \right|}$$ and so $\sum {{a_n}}$ is the
> difference of two convergent series and so is also convergent.

So why are we doing this in a weird roundabout way with the difference of two convergent series?

Why can't we just do:

$${a_n} \le  \left| {{a_n}} \right|$$

thus we can use the direct comparison test?

Is it the positive requirement?

Remembering what you have to prove and what you can just say hmmm that seems fine is the worst part of writing proofs :(

Comment: The comparison test is only valid for series with nonnegative terms. Otherwise, you could use that $-1\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$ and conclude that $\sum (-1)$ converges because $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}$ converges

Comment: Yes, there is a very big difference between proof and "that seems fine." Although this does remind me of an old math joke about the word "obvious."

Comment: Ah, that makes sense thank you for the example! I'm adding this one to my anki deck :)

Answer (score 3):

The proof I would use is even more complicated.

$\sum |a_i|$ is convergent

The Cauchy criteron says:

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists N>0$ such that $n,m > N$ $\implies \sum_\limits{i=n}^m |a_i| < \epsilon$

$\sum_\limits{i=n}^m |a_n| \ge \left |\sum_\limits{i=n}^m a_n \right|$ by the triangle inequality.

i.e.  $|a_n| + |a_{n+1}|+\cdots + |a_m| \ge |a_n + a_{n+1} + \cdots + a_m|$

$\epsilon > \sum_{i=n}^m |a_n|\ge \left|\sum_{i=n}^m a_n\right| \ge  0$

The Cauchy criterion holds for $\sum a_i$

$\sum a_i$ is convergent.

Comment: +1 More complicated, but not a trick. The triangle inequality really explains why the theorem is true.

Comment: I like the proof because it stays close to the definitions of convergent and thus what we need to prove.

Comment: As Ethan said, triangle inequality is key here because it formalises the intuitive idea that it's harder for series to converge absolutely since no cancelling ever happens, so if it converges without any cancelling, it will especially converge if cancelling is introduced. However, this argument also shows a much more subtle point: we need our space to be complete so that our limit actually exists.

Comment: Hmmmm, would I learn about the Cauchy criterion in a Real Analysis class? So far I've only been looking at Calc 1,2,and 3 on Paul's math notes

Comment: @username_entity do you know about Cauchy sequences? You would definitely learn about it in a Real Analysis class. Cauchy criterion that Doug mentions is the theorem that a sequence of real numbers is convergent if and only if it is Cauchy. More generally, it's always true that convergent implies Cauchy in metric spaces (spaces where distance between points makes sense), however the other direction is not true for all metric spaces. It's a special property of a metric space called completeness that the space of real numbers has.

Comment: Yes, Real Analysis, or a "rigorous" calculus book like Spivak.  Wikipedia has some good math pages.  The Cauchy criterion is an extension of Cauchy's limit definition, and it is hard to formally define convergence without it.

Comment: No I haven't heard of Cauchy sequences yet, but I will try to learn Real Analysis after this too! I'm a computer scientist who was always "bad" at math (great compared to all my regular friends, bad compared to you guys), but am trying to get really good at it now so I'm not limited by things and can finally read ML papers and Computer Vision papers lol. You guys are so cool! Thanks for responses :)